# Ставится ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Осуществить подачу напряжения  на трансформатор (,) для чего включить яч.2 РП-10

Ставится ли запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Да, ставится. Это сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным присоединительным.